# create array of date in mongoose node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am very new to `MongoDB`. I want to create an array of date. I am using mongoose with node.js. Below is what I think. Please, will the datatype be saved as date? Thanks.

```
date: {
        type: Array,
        default: Date.now
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It happens that I find the answer myself after research. For anyone that might need it again, the correct way is:

`date: [Date]`

A better explanation is found on Mongoose site : [Mongoose Link](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html)

Answer (score 1):

it should be like :-

date: {
        type: Array,
        default: [Date]
    }

Answer (score 0):

default value will be Array if type is set as Array

```
   date: {
        type: Array,
        default: [Date]
    }
```

Comment: so there is no way to set the array values to date type?

Comment: date type will save date only , you can save dates in type array

Comment: No, it doesn't work. The array values are saved as a string and not date